# How do I install verification package in R?

Tags: r, package

I tried install.packages(verification) but when I try library(verification), I get the error "package ‘fields’ required by ‘verification’ could not be found". How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the fields package, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The 'verification' package requires the fields package to run, do you have 'fields' installed already, or is it not recognizing that you have 'fields' installed?

`install.packages('fields')`

Sorry if that's not helpful, that's the best I could do with what you've provided.